# Is it reasonable to improve an answer to a question that has been put on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing

Does it make sense for me to go back and improve an answer to a question that has already been put on hold?

My thought is that it does, because the question may never get deleted, and may even be re-opened at some point.

Comment: ...also, because unless it's outright deleted, the content will still be discoverable via search engine, so there's still value there.

Comment: Does the question belongs to you? I don't get it (maybe because my english is poor)

Comment: @HugoRocha - No. I am asking a general question. Should we simply never touch an answer to a question which is already closed? Or, if we want to make an answer better, should we do so - even though the question has been closed?

Comment: Oh. Right. I don't want to answer that directly, because i think Monica answer have  sufficed.

Comment: that is kind of the entire point of putting things "on hold" instead of deleting them outright, is to give time for them to be improved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So long as a question is live on the site, I don't think its status should matter in deciding whether to edit an answer.  The same guidelines that would apply to any other edit (substantial, improvement, respect the author's voice, etc) apply.

While you're there, take a look at the question.  Could it be worthy of reopening with an edit?  If so, can you make that edit?  Since your answer-edit is going to bump the question anyway, see if you can help there too.

Comment: If editing both, I'd recommend editing the question first, so it doesn't draw in downvotes/delete votes once the answer edit bumps it.

Comment: Good point.  Also, whichever you do last is what will be linked from the timestamp on the front page.